# HTTP GET works in browser, but doesn't with HTTPWebRequest

Tags: c#, http, get, httpwebrequest

Title explains it. I am trying to change the password of a webpage programmatically using HTTP Web Request. When I do it through Google Chrome (pasting the uri in the address bar), the password change works. Here is the header I get when I inspect in Chrome.

```
Remote Address:10.160.70.55:443
Request URL:https://10.160.70.55/cgi-bin/check_user.cgi?Type=basic&Current=78-62-118-112-106-108-56&Password=98-96-102-96-106-96
Request Method:GET

Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6,ar;q=0.4
Authorization:Digest username="admin", realm="Secure Access", nonce="f3c6fcd9a549a42e9aac22818cb0f5ad", uri="/cgi-bin/check_user.cgi?Type=basic&Current=78-62-118-112-106-108-56&Password=98-96-102-96-106-96", response="cd17523a279f044d086b5bd0245eda0e", qop=auth, nc=0000001b, cnonce="9bd719c27efd9721"
Connection:keep-alive
Host:10.160.70.55
```

When I try to do it programatically, I receive the OK (200) code, but the password change does not work. Here's my code.

```
System.Uri uri2 = new Uri(string.Format("https://{0}/cgi-bin/check_user.cgi?Type=basic&Current=78-62-118-112-106-108-56&Password=98-96-102-96-106-96", ip));
                        HttpWebRequest request2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
                        request2.Accept = "text/html";
                        request2.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "M@ster1");
                        request2.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
                        HttpWebResponse response2 = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                        WriteLog(response2.StatusDescription.ToString());

                        response2.Close();
```

Comment: Can you use fiddler to trace the HTTP request that is sent by your program, and compare with the browser's request to see the difference? That should tell the problem.

Comment: Are those typos uri-uri2, request-request2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Used fiddler as suggested, and it turns out it was the user-agent header. And thank you for correcting the typo L.B. :)